# Update rows while counting rows in other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know if its possible to solve the following action with just one SQL-statement:

**Table A**: User-Table

**Table B**: Entries with foreign-keys for users

The relation between **table A** and **Table B** is `1 -> *`

Because I don't want to count entries in **table B** for a specific user every time, I want to keep a column for this count in the user table. For that I would need a query that updates this column for each user.

Is this possible?

Comment: This new column will require you to count the entries in table B anyway...

Comment: @tsabz unless he only updates the column when he knows that something is changed on table B (could be done with a trigger).

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes but we don't have any clue about how he want to update this column, we just that he wants a query to do this.

Comment: Yes but I would like to update that row maybe once a day and not every second a request is made

Comment: Moreover, a count on table B won't take that much time if the database structure is as simple as the OP says. That's why I don't really see the point of creating a new column.

Comment: The point is that I need this count for frequently requests.. usually the counts should match but if our system will do any mistakes its important that this count is refreshed. And therefore I don't want to spam queries that count those entries for each user and update each user after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: `UPDATE USERS U SET COUNT_ENTRIES=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ENTRIES WHERE USERID=U.ID)`